# try a spider by tornado use proxy, SSL error happen

Tags: ssl, tornado

I run a spider wrote by tornado like https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py,of course ,change the httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient to curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient by

```
httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure('tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient')
```

the spider run on the windows 10.python3+,64.

It is sad that error come:

```
tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlError: HTTP 599: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Anyone saw this? I searched it in the google, but for the demoe of tornado in spider are not much enough, I did not found a answer?

Or anyone can tell me something about the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to overide a method in curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient

```
curl_log = logging.getLogger('tornado.curl_httpclient')
class PersonAsyncHTTPClient(curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient):
    def _curl_create(self):
        curl = pycurl.Curl()

        curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where()) # the soure had no this line.missing this line would come ssl error.

        if curl_log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
            curl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, self._curl_debug)
        if hasattr(pycurl, 'PROTOCOLS'):  # PROTOCOLS first appeared in pycurl 7.19.5 (2014-07-12)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.PROTOCOLS, pycurl.PROTO_HTTP | pycurl.PROTO_HTTPS)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.REDIR_PROTOCOLS, pycurl.PROTO_HTTP | pycurl.PROTO_HTTPS)
        return curl
```

and when we use:

```
http_client = PersonAsyncHTTPClient()
req = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url='https://www.google.com.hk/', proxy_host='', proxy_port=1234)
```

everything come success?

that's all~